# Compositing and creativity with badly cropped/taken photos

Tags: print-design, composition, advertising

Apologies if this has been asked before and if it's inappropriate in this network.

I have a group photo(of people) I have to work with that is poorly taken. The people at the edges are partially cut and so is the top of the heads of others.

It is not official stock photography but is the one they want to use.

I have to now composite it and add it to some branding, text, design elements...etc, like a banner for an event.

Are there any sources of inspiration on how to work with limitations like this?

Or is there any creative advice n how to work with poorly cropped or taken photos?

I did alot of searching, but I think my key words are not descriptive enough to find what I want.

The best I could find was this creative use of different images (possibly intentional) on a cosmetic product.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the photos?

Comment: Hi @TCDesigner. Sorry for the late reply. I will try to post something that looks similar, but not the actual photos as I cannot do so.

Answer (score 1):

if you are a Photoshop expert then you can try to recreate the missing parts. Get a bunch of images of almost similar kind (matching hair color, skin tone, gender etc) and try to recreate those missing portions of the images. Posting images would have been more helpful but i think you might have some privacy issues.

Comment: Not much of an expert but will see what I can try. I will try post something similar

Answer (score 1):

You could create a sort of collage of images from the original photo, cropping in closely on each face, and making sure that the cropping cuts off a variety of sections within each face, so that the people who are cropped in your current photo don't look so out of place. There's an example here: https://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-photo-funny-collage-young-people-making-faces-wide-angle-shots-image36841785 (sorry, I am on my iPad and I can't get the photo to post correctly). I did a google search on "collage of faces" to find this example, and there are some more good ones there that you might want to check out.

Once you have created the collage, you can treat the branding elements like they do in your sample picture--on a banner above or below the collage. You might even want to make a your collage into a duotone with one of the colors from the logo (duotone is like a b&w image, only it uses a different color instead of black). This can help subdue the differing backgrounds behind each face. Just do a google search for instructions about how to make a duotone in Photoshop--my process is to add appearance layers on top of my image; first a B&W layer, and then one of the color layers (although I can't remember which color layer I use at the moment). Anyway, I think you should be able to find some instructions if you do a search.